# testing django-tasks

Tags: django

I am trying to write a test that involves running a django-tasks task. The problem is I can't seem to get the tasks to go beyond the "scheduled" status.

I have set

> DJANGOTASK_DEMON_THREAD = True

in my settings, for simplicity.

```
ptask = djangotasks.task_for_function(f)
djangotasks.run_task(ptask)

while ptask.status!='successful':
    ptask = djangotasks.task_for_function(f)
    print ptask.status
    time.sleep(5)
```

This is what I'm attempting, which works well outside of tests.

edit: fixed typo

Comment: Just to be sure, `succesful` (with 1s) is a typo? It should be `successful`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks, but the issue is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't assign a task worker. In your django directory :

```
> python manage.py taskd run
```

your scheduled tasks would be executed by this "taskd".